# blastdbcmd - Too many positional arguments <1>, the offending value: %f

Tags: windows, cmd, bioinformatics, fasta, blast

I'm trying to use blastdbcmd - when I type the following on cmd

```
blastdbcmd -db databaseBLAST -entry_batch -outfmt "%f" -out test_query.txt
```

the following error pops up:

```
Error: Too many positional arguments <1>, the offending value: %f
```

I typed `%f` so that it's in Fasta format, and even after spending so much time on the internet to figure out, I still have no idea what to do for this error. Would you please be able to help me out?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a little bit late, but I think this may be yet another case of UTF-8 versus ISO-latin finding a way to annoy:

I had the same problem with a different query using `blastn`, but the offending value was `-db`. I found out that it was an encoding problem with the "-" part of the command. I.e. if you are copy-pasting the commands from Mac or a pdf or so what looks like "%f" or "-" to us may be not. Try typing all the command instead of copy-pasting.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not with the `-outfmt` argument. It is that `-entry_batch` requires a file name. Also, you don't need to specify `-outfmt '%f'` since Fasta format is the default output.

Here is the command line that you want:

`blastdbcmd.exe -db databaseBLAST -entry 'all' -out test_query.txt`

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Pure guess : remove the quotes, double the `%` or more probably both.

`%f` is the default according to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was a very difficult to spot look-alike for "-" after copy-pasting part of a command. Make sure the minus-signs are real minus signs!